# blackjack odds on 6 deck shoe

Tags: probability

In a 6 deck shoe,  the question is....
if the person before  'hits' ,when the "book" says "stand", does it only lower your odds, for you to hit the card you need.
I've argued that when a"bad" player makes a bad "hit", and the other players get disgusted and walk from table, the "bad" player is only a distraction and doesn't change your odds (in a 6 deck shoe)
True or false?

Comment: in other words, the person before you drawing a card when he shouldn't can also make you draw the card you want(win your hand instead of lose your husband)

Comment: True ! The cards in the shoe can be considered to be complete random. Thus the action of the player before you only has the effect that one or more random cards get replaced by other random cards. Hence your expectation value remains the same. Of course in a specific situation the result may change (bad or good). But in the long run such effects cancel.

Comment: Whether a player takes a card when they shouldn't or vice-versa has no effect on the odds. You will often see other players blame players for doing it, but no so often praising them when it works in their favor.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, a player asking for a card doesn't change the odds for you.

On the contrary, it could actually help. That's because you don't have to take a decision until the card for that player had been shown. After that, probabilities had changed, and you can chose more accurately and with less variance the good move.

Of course, though, experienced players get angry because they get frustrated when an inexperienced player wins money playing simply through luck.